# How copy a file to the same directory as the .exe file

Tags: windows, cmake

This i probably trival, but I haven't figured it out yet. I have a .ini file in the same directory as the source code and I want cmake to copythis inifile.ini to the directory where the .exe file is generated. This dirctory can vary depending on if I do a release or Debug build and if I do a insource or out-of-source build. I have come this far:

```
configure_file(${myapp_SOURCE_DIR}/src/myinifile.ini
               ${myapp_BINARY_DIR}/bin/${????}/myinifile.ini COPYONLY)
```

But I need to include bin/Debug or bin/Release in the destination path depending on the build type. Is there a cmake variable I can use that points to the actual directory where the .exe will be generated. Or what is the best way to do  this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get a `LOCATION` property to find the output path for your target. Next you can use its value in `add_custom_command`:

```
get_target_property(exepath target_name LOCATION)
get_filename_component(outputpath "${exepath}" PATH)
add_custom_command(TARGET target_name POST_BUILD
    COMMAND "${CMAKE_COMMAND}" -E copy_if_different "${myapp_SOURCE_DIR}/src/myinifile.ini" "${outputpath}")
```

This code will automatically handle build type dependency.

Comment: Can't get LOCATION property from target_name, it is empty. I have defined target with add_executable(target_name WIN32 ${SRCS})

Comment: @lgwest code I posted works perfectly for me. Where have you placed this code? It should go after the `add_executable` command.

Comment: Ok, it seems to be correct, got it to work on a small test case, but not on my real project, but that must be another error.